# Weather Web Service by Postal Code?

Tags: data-request, usa, weather, postal-code

I'm looking for either a website, a web service, an RSS feed, etc. that would allow me to look up current and historic weather info for a particular zipcode or region in the U.S., specifically:

- Barometric pressure
- Precipitation
- Temperature
- Humidity

Googling this turned up a couple of candidates such as:

- Weather Web Service
- National Digital Forecast Database

But none of these supply all the above info all at once. Does something like this exist as open source/free, or am I going to have to wrangle/"Frankenstein" this together myself by calling out to multiple services? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Weather API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=index) from Wunderground allows 500 free requests per day (with registration) and has a [geolookup](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/geolookup) endpoint for finding the nearest weather station.

[image]

Once you have the nearest weather station, you can use other endpoints like [forecast](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast) and [history](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history).

The full list of endpoints is [here](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/index).

Comment: Glad it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The national weather service has a REST-based API. You can query by zipcodes, cities, lat/lon and bounding boxes. Below is a link to the documentation.

http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php

Comment: That seems to be for forecasts -- do they have historical data?

Comment: The queries can take a 'begin' and 'end'. Here is what the documentation says: begin  2004-04-27T12:00  The beginning time for which you want NDFD data.   If the string is empty, the beginnng time is assumed to be the earliest available time in the database. Time should be in UTC time.  
end  2004-04-30T12:00  The ending time for which you want NDFD data.   If the string is empty, the ending time is assumed to be the last available time in the database. Time should be in UTC time.

Comment: Um ... but it says it's 'NDFD' data ... which is forecast data.  So it might not be the actual historic weather for a given day & place, but what they had forecasted for that day & place.