# Hourly temperature data for specific locations (Arkansas) for the year 2014

Tags: data-request, weather

I am searching for a site which gives hourly temperature data for specific locations in Arkansas (I have zip codes) for the year 2014. Please assist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weather Web Service by Postal Code?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4665/weather-web-service-by-postal-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here: http://www.climate.gov/hourlysub-hourly-observational-data-hourly-global-%E2%80%93-gis-data-locator.  It looks like you can go to "View Data", then select the stations of interest from the map, then specify the dates and data elements that you want.  It does not guarantee that hourly data will be available from every station.

Comment: The link is now dead, unfortunately.

Comment: @KevinP. Yes, unfortunately the link is now dead and on that website it looks like they don't have any hourly data available any more.  The Weather Underground information in the answer found by following the link in the comment on the original question still appears to be working and looks like a good option going forward.